# Unit test of Spring Webflow which uses bean configuration inheritance by extending AbstractXmlFlowExecutionTests

Tags: spring, junit4, spring-webflow-2

We have upgraded Spring WebFlow from 1 to 2.4.1. Now we need to rewrite all of our Unit tests. One issue is stopping us dead in our tracks. Most of our flows still import action beans and forms, as we are still using XML configurations. In addition, all of the action beans inherit configuration via an abstract bean reference in the webflow configuration file. So we have the following bean reference in our webflowContext.xml:

```
<bean id="serviceInjected" abstract="true">
    <property name="serviceLocator" ref="serviceLocator"/>
    <property name="misAssembler" ref="misAssembler"/>
    <property name="formObjectScope" value="FLOW"/>
</bean>
```

All of the Action beans thus inherit the serviceLocator, misAssembler and formObjectScope. When I try to unit test the flows, the tests fails because there is no "serviceInjected" bean reference. So my question is:: How can we insert bean configuration inheritance into the test before we attempt to start the flow. Using *configureFlowBuilderContext* will not work as this change the ApplicationContext and not the ExternalContext. I have only seen one other reference to this on the internet and that question was not answered, so here is hoping I have better luck.

Comment: Just FYI. We had an error in the test application context XML file. Entering in the 'serviceInjected' bean as above into the testApplicationContext resolved the issue. Now the abstract inheritance is working as expected.